# Reverse for 'update-delete' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<code_token>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Tags: django-rest-framework

views.py

```py
class UpdateDeleteAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReservingSerializer
    queryset = Reserve.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'code_token'  


class PreUpdateDeleteAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PreEditSerializer
    queryset = Reserve.objects.all()

    def post(self, request,format=None):
        data= request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           return self.get(request,data)

    def get(self,request,*args):
        data1 = {
            reverse('update-delete',args=args,request=request)
        } 
        return Response(data1)
```

urls.py

```py
path('edit/<slug:code_token>/',UpdateDeleteAPIView.as_view(), name='update-delete'),
path('preedit/',PreUpdateDeleteAPIView.as_view(), name='pre-update-delete'),
```

hello, i tried several time to do this and i got an error! whats your advice to currect this error? i think there is a problem in `PreUpdateDeleteAPIView` class and my methods...
i will be thankfull if you tell me your suggesstions.

Comment: Your `PreUpdateDeleteAPIView` does not have any slug, hence since it has no slug, it can not redirect to the delete view that *needs* a slug to know *what* to delete.

Comment: i dont wanna use slug in PreUpdateDeleteAPIView, i just wanna get a code and post it to UpdateDeleteAPIView.